# Как исправить "Unexpected token while deserializing object"?

Tags: c#, .net, json, vkontakte-api, dll

Ошибка:

```
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unexpected token while deserializing object: PropertyName. Path '', line 1, position 33.
```

Код:

```
public class Audio
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int owner_id { get; set; }
        public string artist { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string duration { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string lyrics_id { get; set; }
        public int genre_id { get; set; }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (!Settings1.Default.auth) { Thread.Sleep(500); }

        string content;
        using (var request = new HttpRequest())
        {
            request.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent();
            HttpResponse response = request.Get("https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?user_id=" + Settings1.Default.id + "&v=5.45&access_token=" + Settings1.Default.token);

            content = response.ToString();
        }

        JToken token = JToken.Parse(content);

        audioList = token["response"].Children().Skip(1).Select(c => c.ToObject<Audio>()).ToList();

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < audioList.Count; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(audioList[i].artist + " - " + audioList[i].title);
            }
        }
        );

    }
```

Вот это храниться в "c":

```
{"items": [
  {
    "id": 284972681,
    "owner_id": 120083515,
    "artist": "Crown The Empire",
    "title": "Wake Me Up",
    "duration": 262,
    "date": 1401419688,
    "url": "http://cs4979.vk.me/u4769422/audios/70356b92ad95.mp3?extra=yWpDKU29H3yJhlMy3OwP4ofcFTVwpZQ3JdGLo-mrSRYo-kT8WsQfayUjJdPSQIvAbBMty_IZZ0PxuPTT2er0cxd2wyg7zO8mRw3uCDPW_MrYCX948zpcO3EWI4C5zMis4VE9OqjAC1mu",
    "lyrics_id": 9594663,
    "genre_id": 18
  },
  {
    "id": 276569510,
    "owner_id": 120083515,
    "artist": "Crown The Empire",
    "title": "Lead Me Out Of The Dark (piano)",
    "duration": 197,
    "date": 1398096273,
    "url": "http://cs1-36v4.vk-cdn.net/p23/d87f502c80ba85.mp3?extra=kIpvu8XGPeyLoRDrQ8nN4Zddx3WI2x_Bub08dnCEre2I6Qb--MQW0_ycx9hEeYB8iyPg_iv3obpAthKJ255Z2ijx6nTN6T2JMwTMDKEOr069C2-mVhN0jpmSZFV1MWMDy5PBAF6ULONX",
    "lyrics_id": 23152966,
    "genre_id": 1
  }
]}
```

Помогите пожалуйста! Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я с Newtonsoft'ов не работал, поэтому возможно более элегантное решение.
У Вас:
`token["response"].Children()` - вы спускаетесь в тело элемента responce:

```
{"items": [
    {
        "id": 284972681,
        ...
    },
    {
        "id": 276569510,
        ...
    }
]}
```

А вам нужно спуститься до уровня item'ов:

```
token["response"]["items"]
```

Т.к. Вы работаете с JToken, тело items представляет собой как объект, результат будет:

```
{[
    {
        "id": 284972681,
        ...
    },
    {
        "id": 276569510,
        ...
    }
]}
```

Поэтому нужно спуститься до тела этого объекта.
token["response"]["items"].Children()

```
[
    {
        "id": 284972681,
        ...
    },
    {
        "id": 276569510,
        ...
    }
]
```

Т.е. у Вас должно получиться

```
audioList = token["response"]["items"].Children().Select(c => c.ToObject<Audio>())
```